# Launching an app with bluetooth

Tags: android, bluetooth

I am working on an android app that needs to be able to toggle a setting on one phone after a bluetooth message from the other. I need to know how to make it so that when the message is received, my app opens to handle the request. Similar to how nfc tags work, you can launch an app with it, then read the data on the tag. I need to be able to launch my app, then read the data inside the bluetooth message. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The message can't launch an app directly, you have to design a background service wich listen bluetooth message and trigger the app.

Moreover, you can start this service at start up with a broadcast receiver

Comment: I was half expecting to have to do this. How bad will this affect battery life?

Comment: I don't really know for the battery, but i think it does not consume much more than let the bluetooth on.